# F-score and standardized Beta for heteroscedasticity-corrected covariance matrix (hccm) in R

Tags: r, lm, anova, r-car

I have multiple regression models which failed Breusch-Pagan tests, and so I've recalculated the variance using a heteroscedasticity-corrected covariance matrix, like this: `coeftest(lm.model,vcov=hccm(lm.model))`. `coeftest()` is from the `lmtest` package, while `hccm()` is from the `car` package.

I'd like to provide F-scores and standardized betas, but am not sure how to do this, because the output looks like this...

```
t test of coefficients:

                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)     0.000261   0.038824    0.01    0.995  
age             0.004410   0.041614    0.11    0.916  
exercise       -0.044727   0.023621   -1.89    0.059 .
tR             -0.038375   0.037531   -1.02    0.307  
allele1_num     0.013671   0.038017    0.36    0.719  
tR:allele1_num -0.010077   0.038926   -0.26    0.796  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Any advice on how to report these so they are as consistent as possible with the standard `summary()` and `Anova()` output from R and `car`, and the function `std_beta()` from the `sjmisc` package?

Comment: Perhaps informing a new user _why_ their question merits a downvote would be more helpful...

Comment: Yes thanks. Still don't know how this works other than sometimes I ask questions as close to the protocol as I can and the answers magically appear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this question, here was my solution. It is not particularly elegant, but it works.

I simply used the function for std_beta as a template, and then changed the input for the standard error to that derived from the `std_beta()` function.

```
# This is taken from std_beta function from sj_misc package.
# =====================================


b <-coef(lm.model) # Same Estimate
b <-b[-1] # Same intercept
fit.data <- as.data.frame(stats::model.matrix(lm.model)) # Same model.

fit.data <- fit.data[, -1] # Keep intercept
fit.data <- as.data.frame(sapply(fit.data, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) 
                          to_value(x, keep.labels = F)
                          else x))

sx <- sapply(fit.data, sd, na.rm = T)
sy <- sapply(as.data.frame(lm.model$model)[1], sd, na.rm = T)

beta <- b * sx/sy
se <-coeftest(lm.model,vcov=hccm(lm.model))[,2] # ** USE HCCM covariance for SE **
se <- se[-1]
beta.se <- se * sx/sy

data.frame(beta = beta, ci.low = (beta - beta.se * 
            1.96), ci.hi = (beta + beta.se * 1.96))
```

For the F-scores, I just squared the t-values. 
I hope this saves someone some time.